# Custom resampling method in caret

Tags: r, caret, resampling

I need to create a custom resampling method in R package **caret** where: For each leave-pair-out-cross-validation, from the training set I derive new data using a function I implemented. Then it is used as training set, and tested against the 2 instances left out. In the next iteration new data will be derived from the new training set resampled.

In the **caret** custom models manual page it is showed how to make a custom model but I would like to make a **custom resampling *method*** in the *trainControl* function that can be used with any *train* model. Is that possible in **caret** ?

So to recap, I need some sort of LGOCV that for each iteration takes the input training set and transforms it in a new dataframe with a function I created that will be used as actual training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you had 8 training set samples would this scheme result in `choose(8,2) = 28` resamples? Also, I'm assuming that this isn't two *nested* leave-one-out loops.

If so, here is a solution that might breakdown with large sample sizes.

```
num_samps <- 8
holdout <- combn(num_samps, 2)
in_training <- apply(holdout, 2, 
                     function(x, all) all[!(all %in% x)],
                     all = 1:num_samps)

## need a more effcient way of doing this:
index <- vector(mode = "list", length = ncol(in_training))
for(i in 1:ncol(in_training)) index[[i]] <- in_training[,i]
## cosmetic:
names(index) <- caret:::prettySeq(seq(along = index))

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", ## this will be ignored since  
                     ## we supply index below
                     index = index)
```

Max